# usbmon have multiple nodes

Tags: usb, debugging

Why usbmon have multiple node for single bus in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/` folder (like 2s, 2u, 2t) ?

When I trying to sniff usb trafic with my device, it looks like some USB frames are missed. (My application uses U2F-HiD to communicate with device, and some data packets longer than 128 bytes.)

What is a proper way to sniff all trafic, and parse it into usable form? (any tutorial will be very useful)
Right now I just use `cat` redirected into file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt` in the kernel source:

> Two formats are supported currently: the original, or '1t' format, and
>   the '1u' format. The '1t' format is deprecated in kernel 2.6.21. The '1u'
>   format adds a few fields, such as ISO frame descriptors, interval, etc.
>   It produces slightly longer lines, but otherwise is a perfect superset
>   of '1t' format.

Then it continues to explain what the fields mean. The `1s` etc. nodes provide some kind of status (like `nreaders` = number of readers = consumers of usbmon events), but I don't know details, and never had to use them.

You can use tools like `wireshark` or [vusbanalyzer](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/) to more comfortably analyze traffic. Capture via `tcpdump` and post-mortem analysis with `wireshark` is also possible:

```
sudo tcpdump -i usbmon1 -w usbmon.pcap &
```

**Edit**

You can load the `usbmon.pcap` file into wireshark, just like other pcap files obtained by tcpdump or otherwise.

IIRC, `usbhid-dump` reads and dumps the HID **descriptor** *as obtained by the kernel* (so it doesn't obtain it by exchanging messages), and  there were some kernel API changes and/or you had to unbind the USB device before it could could access the HID, but I forgot the details.

You can access the HID descriptor directly, both raw and the kernel parse, by mounting `debugfs`

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

and then looking at `/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc`. `hid-rd` can also parse the raw HID descriptor.

And if you are just after the HID **reports**, use the corresponding `hidraw` device.

Comment: I also tried `usbhid-dump`, but it blocks (devices doesn't receive frames). Any ideas why he works so?
`usbhid-dump  --entity=all -t 0 --address=2:5 `

Comment: How I can than parse this tcpdumped file?